# PHP preg_replace(): Unknown

Tags: php, modifier

I get this warning message - "Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '+'" when I run this code:

```
$newString = preg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $originalString);
return $newString;
```

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add delimiters to your expression:

```
$newString = preg_replace("~[[:alpha:]]...~"
```

Here, I used the tilde `~`, but you can use something else if you prefer.